# Convert Array to Query string in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, query-string

I am trying to get a artist profile from Echonest. I need to have a parameter named 'bucket' multiple times in the query string. I am trying to set it with an array with the object that I am passing. Is this possible to pass this in an array?

I have this:

```
bucket:['biographies', 'images', 'artist_location', 'urls'];
```

I want this:

```
bucket=biographies&bucket=images&bucket=artist_location&bucket=urls
```

Client:

```
getArtistProfile = function(artistName){
    var params = {
        format:'json',
        bucket:['biographies', 'images', 'artist_location', 'urls'],
        name:artistName
    };

     Meteor.call('getEchoNestData', params, function(error, result) {
        if (error)
            console.warn(error);
        else
            console.log(result);
    });
};
```

Server Method:

```
getEchoNestData:function(type, params){
    check(type, String);

    params.api_key = Meteor.settings.echonest.apiKey;

    var result = HTTP.get('http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile' + type, {timeout:5000, params:params});
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: i don't think there is a convenient way of doing that. I would just write a for loop or use `_.reduce` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be misinterpreting your question, but it seems like you are asking how to dynamically build a set of query string parameters. You could have a simple helper like this:

```
function getParams( arr ) {
    var params = [];

    for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i ) {
        params.push( 'bucket=' + arr[ i ] );
    }

    return params.join( '&' );
}
```

and pass in your array of param values like this:

`var params = getParams( bucket );`

http://jsfiddle.net/7vaLcjxs/