# How to pass an array from view to controller? Using Laravel

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, view, controller

I'm with an issue for some days that  I can't solve.

I should have a javascript/ajax/jQuery function in my View that creates an array and send the user to a new page using the Route "/modulos/contas_ti/gerar_protocolo"

Here is my javascript:

```
function check() {
    // I don't know how many numbers I will have in my array.
    // It will be dinamic. Can be [1, 2] or [1, 4, 5, 6] or anything else.
    var array = [1, 2];

    // I would like to pass 'array' in the URL below as parameter
    window.location.href = "{{URL::to('/modulos/contas_ti/gerar_protocolo')}}"
}
```

My Route:

```
// Maybe pass the array at the end of 'gerar_protocolo'? 
// Like 'gerar_protocolo[]=' ?

Route::get('/modulos/contas_ti/gerar_protocolo', 'ContasTI\ContasTIController@gerarProtocolo');
```

My Controller:

```
// How to pass the array as parameter inside ()? I also need to 
// pass the array to the new view using 'with', right? 
// Like with->('datas', $data);

public function gerarProtocolo() {
    return view('modulos.contas-ti.gerar_protocolo');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it as a request parameter

```
function check() {
    var array = [1, 2];

    window.location.href = "{{URL::to('/modulos/contas_ti/gerar_protocolo')}}" + "?array[]=1&array[]=2";
}
```

Controller :

```
public function gerarProtocolo(Request $request) {
    $data = request('array');
    return view('modulos.contas-ti.gerar_protocolo', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Hi, Misa. Thank you! The thing is that I don't know exactly how many numbers my array will have. It will be dinamic. I added this obs to the post now.

Comment: This might help http://jsfiddle.net/7vaLcjxs/19/ I get it from here with a modification to array parameter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736718/convert-array-to-query-string-in-meteor

Comment: Hello, Misa! It worked, I made a  few changes and it worked! Thank  you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do is, create one form with hidden variable than when you are calling you javascript check() function, store the array value in the hidden variable and than use javascript form.submit() method.

Answer (score 0):

`function check() {
    var array = [1, 2, n];
    var myArray= encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(array));
    window.location.href = "{{URL::to('/modulos/contas_ti/gerar_protocolo')}}" + "?array=" + myArray;
}`

Controller :

`public function gerarProtocolo() {
    $data = request->json()->('array');
    return view('modulos.contas-ti.gerar_protocolo', compact('data'));
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array to json using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
json_data = JSON.stringify(my_array);
```

So then you can form your url as: `'example.com/api?json_data='+json_data`
Therefore in your controller, simply retrieve it by calling:

```
$data = request()->get('json_data');
$data_array = json_decode($data, true); //converts to array
return view('modulos.contas-ti.gerar_protocolo', compact('data_array'));
```

In your view, the variable `$data_array` will be available for usage.